# Can't resolve 'fs' , 'os','path','querystring' in in 'C:\Users\..\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib' in React Js application

Tags: reactjs, text-to-speech

I want to make a React Application which uses IBM's Watson AI like Text to speech conversion. For that I have generated TTS service on IBM Cloud . added Credentials and keys in the code. but when I run the application via npm start or yarn start , it gives me errors like below :

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:..\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:..\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\auth\utils'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:..\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\auth\utils'

Can anyone help me with above errors. It seems error from node_modules.

Is it with some version related issues?
Any SDKs,Packages need to installed to run the application ?

Request you to help me with solutions and suggestion to resolved the above errors.

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to use backend module in the client, but it's impossible. `fs`, `os` and `path` are only available in node.js' environment

Answer (score 0):

This error indeed seems to deal with missing node modules that you try to import. Try to run this command in order to install all dependencies that you miss:

```
npm install -g npm-install-missing
npm-install-missing
```

Alternatively, you may try to install all dependencies listed in your `package.json` this way:

```
npm install
```

If you need to install some specific dependency and you know its name, this solution will install it and add to your `package.json`:

```
npm install {package-name} --save
```

Comment: npm install -g npm-install-missing , installed all missing dependencies but still the same errors as above. Can't resolve 'path','fs','os','util','stream' etc...